# Would an index on a table be beneficial in this case?

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing

Ive got a table with a many rows, currently no fields are unique. I've got a userid field and an gameid field and some other rows storing information on the games the users have played. As a user plays the game the score is updated so there are quite alot of update queries happening on this table and it's starting to get pretty large.

Would it be beneficial adding another field thats an index and then storing a string such as userid_gameid which would then mean updates were faster in the table if I do my update queries so where index=10_10 (example)

Thanks

Comment: A table with a few rows that's starting to get pretty large?  Confusing!

Comment: Ooops, fixed that now, but yes theres lots of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add a noddy field for userid + gameid, instead, create an index that *includes both columns*.  If the two columns taken together are intended to be unique then make this the primary key of the table.

`CREATE INDEX myIndex ON myTable (userid, gameid)`

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realise that was possible but now I see! So does that mean that if i make an index for two, my update queries as they are should be faster?

Comment: _Much_ faster Jack - your updates will go from having to read the entire table each time to just having to perform a simple lookup.

Comment: @Jack, no so much the updates (writing data in the database) as the lookup speed. It will take the database engine less time to find the row to update, so things will be faster. Where faster means it could reduce the time from minutes to fractions of a second.

Comment: Just tried this, works perfectly! I'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: @Jack - nice one, don't neglect your indexes and primary / foreign keys - they'll pay dividends!  Enjoy!

Comment: +1 For the use of "noddy" (actually, +1 for the answer, but very nice use of a word that sent me scrambling for a dictionary).

Comment: @pst - none of the dictionaries I could find came up with what I intended the word to mean.  :)  I guess 'stupid person / idiot' is _close_, but I certainly didn't mean to be derogatory - it's the field that would be stupid.  :)

Comment: @Will_A, compound primary keys are not a great idea on InnoDB tables though, as the PK gets included on every secondary key. If you have many indexes your disk usage will balloon.

Comment: @Johan - I suspect this is the case for many DBMSs - it's certainly true of SQL Server as well.  I'd suggest a compound primary key isn't necessarily a bad idea - perhaps in some circumstances it's not ideal, but I wouldn't avoid it just to keep down the size of other indexes.

Comment: @Will A That's how I auto-converted the meaning in head: "a simpleton field" ;-)